# Combine R, C++ and Fortran

Tags: r, fortran, rcpp

I am trying to reimplement an R function using C++ and RCpp to speed up the computation.  And in the C++ implementation,  I need to use a Fortran function `mvtdst` found in [link](https://github.com/zhanxw/libMvtnorm/blob/master/libMvtnorm/mvt.f).

> ```
> #include <Rcpp.h>
> #include "mvtnorm.h" 
> using namespace Rcpp;
>
> // [[Rcpp::export]] 
> NumericVector pmvnorm_rcpp(NumericVector upper, NumericMatrix corr) 
> {
>    double error;
>    double mvnP = pmvnorm_P(2, upper, corr, &error) ;
>    return mvnP ;  
> }
>
> /*** R
> pmvnorm_rcpp(c(1.5,1.5),c(0.0))
> */
> ```

Here, `pmvnorm_P` is defined in the mvtnorm.cpp file.

All the files found in [link](https://github.com/zhanxw/libMvtnorm/tree/master/libMvtnorm) are kept in the working directory along with the RcppWrapper.cpp file.

When I compile my RcppWrapper.cpp file using `sourceCpp()` function in RCpp package, it gives the following error.

> mvtnorm.o:mvtnorm.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `mvtdst_'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("RcppWrapper.cpp") : 
>     Error occurred building shared library.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you provide the Rcpp code you tried?

Comment: I have tried this `// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector pmvnorm_rcpp(NumericVector upper, NumericMatrix corr) {

  double error;
  double mvnP = pmvnorm_P(2, upper, corr, &error) ;
  
  
  return mvnP ;
}`. Here

Comment: Here, `pmvnorm_P` is defined in the [link](https://github.com/zhanxw/libMvtnorm/blob/master/libMvtnorm/mvtnorm.cpp) which call the fortran function `mvtdst`.

Comment: Please put the relevant code in your question. You keep changing the details of the question, so you're going to get divergent answers depending on which version of the question was in place when the answer was written.  We also need to know how you are compiling your code and how you are linking it, since those seem to be the broken steps in your process.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Instead of using this separate library it is probably easier to use the API provided by the `mvtnorm` package, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51294364/8416610.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have code in *two* sources files

- `mvtnorm.cpp` calling your backend function `pmvnorm_P()`
- another file providing it

then you also *must* provide link instructions.  Simply put, `sourceCpp()` is only intentended and working for one-file solutions (unless you give link instructions).

Simplest fix: *just create a package* assembling *all* your files in `src/`.

Comment: Dear Dirk, Thank you for your suggestion. I created a package by putting all files (.cpp , .h and .f ) along with a make file and solved the problem.

Comment: Nice, and good to hear.  You should *not* need a Makefile, at most a Makevars.  R knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Fortran and C++ mangle the names of functions differently.  It looks like `mvtdst` is the name of your Fotran function. (Right?)  You need to "mangle" that by hand when called from C++.  So instead of calling `mvtdst`, call `mvtdst_` with the trailing underscore.

Unfortunately, compilers are not consistent in the mangling, so this will not be portable. (To make it portable, you'll need some sort of preprocessing that matched the mangling to the compiler.)

Comment: Yes, `MVTDST` is the Fortran function and within the C++ function it uses as `mvtdst_`.  Here, I am using C++ code from [link](https://github.com/zhanxw/libMvtnorm). When I compile the C++ code alone it works fine. But it fails when I try to use `sourceCpp()` function in RCpp package.  Thanks for your information.