# How can I build a portable R program that runs Fortran code?

Tags: r, gcc, fortran, shared-libraries, gfortran

We have a Fortran economic model that we want to use within a GUI, so I built an R program that imports the Fortran code with `dyn.load()` and launches the model by using `.Fortran()`.

In order to import the Fortran code into R, I compiled my .f90 files into .o files with this line :

`gfortran -c file1.f90 file2.f90`

Then, I ran this line :

`gfortran -shared file1.o file2.o -o out.so`

From R, I load the file with `dyn.load('out.so')` and I can use the subroutines I wrote by calling them with `.Fortran()` in R.

Now, everything works fine on my computer, but if I take this .so file and my R code and send it to someone else (which is the original goal), the other person gets this error :

```
unable to load shared object '/path/to/.so':
  dlopen(/path/to/.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7/libgfortran.4.dylib
```

I searched on the Web and as I understand this, it's a problem with linked libraries that aren't included in the .so file. Can I include them all in a package that would be independent, and send the resulting .so file to someone so that he/she could run the R code without having to recompile everything?

Thanks!

Comment: You likely want to look in to wrapping fortran in C++ and using the `Rcpp` package.  That is about as portable as you can get.

Comment: this [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911179/combine-r-c-and-fortran) might be relevant.

Comment: The Fortran libraries your `.so` files require must be available to your "someone else". So that user could install the Fortran compiler you used. You can also try to make your `.so` link to a local copy of the `libgfortran.4.dylib`. How you do that depends on the OS and the compiler one uses. You seem to be using macOS or Mac OS X. User will have to install the same compiler as you.